# Running phantomjs with shell_exec under cron job

Tags: cron, sudoers

I have something like this:

```
$re = shell_exec("sudo /usr/local/share/phantomjs --version");
```

Unfortunately this gives me another problem:

```
 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
 Sorry, try again.
```

User that cron runs under is *bokac* so Using *visudo* as *root* I added line in */etc/sudoers* :

```
  bokac ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/share/phantomjs
```

I have to mention that */usr/local/share/phantomjs* is a sym link to executable under */usr/local/share/phantomjs-master/bin/phantomjs*.

Basically, this is not working, I keep getting error message stated above. Is my *sudoers* line correct? What am I doing or not doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this was solved by chmod 0777 on executable file that sym link was pointing at, and no need for changing sudoers any more. That made more confusion then help.